# AWS Route53 - Site not working. Works when opened using public IP

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I have a basic Django website running on an AWS EC2 instance. Command I use to run server:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Website is accessible when I used the public IP of the EC2 instance in the browser.

[EC2 Security group settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVs5Y.png)

Next step I tried was to set up DNS using AWS Route53. Created a hosted domain as shown here -
[Hosted Domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFVOq.jpg)

I have added record sets for www.mysite.com. and mysite.com.

My domain is registered with namecheap.com and I have added the 4 name servers shown in my hosted domain to it in the custom DNS section under name servers.

The state of my domain on whatsmydns good. I have created a health check under route53 and it shows red. The website is not accessible when I type in www.mysite.com in the browser.

I tried pinging the domain. It times out but maps to the correct public IP.

What am I missing here? Please advise.

Comment: Can you give us the domain ? If you can access it through the ec2 hostname/IP it's probably related to the DNS. It can take some time (72 hours) for DNS changes to propagate globally.

Comment: I would have also checked like

ping DNS and make sure we are getting public IP, if not probably DNS has been not propagated as pointed by @ranman

if you are getting public IP make sure you have configured intended port and path in Route 53 configuration

Comment: Have you checked your security group settings? I'm guessing you may have set "Allow All Traffic" from your IP so you could SSH, but left port 8000 closed/blocked to the rest of the world.

Comment: Thanks a  lot! Tried pinging the domain and it maps to the correct public IP but times out. Updated my question with EC2 security group settings for inbound. For 8000 it is Type: Custom TCP Rule, Protocol: TCP, Port Range: 8000, Source: 0.0.0.0/0. I doubt if I need to make port specific settings in DNS. By the way, I open the website using public IP by typing http://<public IP>:8000.

Comment: It seems to work when I type in http://www.example.com:8000/. May be I need to add another alias?

Comment: example.com will by default hit port 80. If it works with example.com:8000 your DNS is working fine... you just need to serve your content on port 80.